# Capture with CasperJS does not render web fonts

Tags: capture, casperjs, webfonts

I'm using [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) in my page. It works well in Chrome. But when I use the `capture()`method from CasperJS, I see "crosses" instead of icons.

I didn't find any hack to achieve that.

```
phantomjs --version
1.9.7
casperjs --version
1.1.0-beta3
```

Comment: Are you on windows or on linux? What does it print if you add `console.log("version: " + phantom.version.major+"."+phantom.version.minor+"."+phantom.version.patch);` at the beginning of your script? Have you tried `wait`-ing a little before capturing? It may be necessary because webfonts are not loaded as part of the DOM.

Comment: I'm on OSX and Debian, I found this: http://arunoda.me/blog/phantomjs-webfonts-build.html then it works well on OSX but on my linux some libc are missing. I didn't make this upgrade and finally I cut my icons into images to bypass this issue. It's now OK for icons but bad render for fonts. Yes I have a 1s waiting time.